# Keeping ADODB connection open for a while

Tags: .net, web-services, interop, com-interop, adodb

I have a problem with ADO-DB Connection to SQL Server in the ADO.Net Application.
I am opening the connection in a web-service when it starts and closing it when it ends.Meaning the connection is open as long as the service runs.
I am passing the connection to a COM dll which actually handles the transactions.
I am now facing one issue that,The command executes throws exception after a while though the same execute worked before.But the connection state shows Open only.
So we have to close the connection and open it and retry the transaction.This way it works.
But I want to know the root cause an actual solution for this.
One more thing,We have only one client right now.

Comment: What exception do you have? What do you mean by opening connection when service starts? Do you mean opening connection per request or only once for the whole lifetime of the application? What does COM component do with the connection? Improve your question because you missed very important details.

Comment: From C++(COM dll) the exception is just E_FAIL.When I tested the same thing in .Net the exception is "Connection failure".I am opening the connection when my webservice starts.(Only for the whole life  time of application).COM component is the one which actually does all the transactions.The connection object is passed to the COM Component.

Answer (score 0):

Keeping connection opened for the whole lifetime of the application is a bad practice. Connection can timeout, there can be some network problems, etc. Connection simply can fail and there is no way to avoid that - you must catch exception and somehow handle it. Also this doesn't allow you to process multiple requests concurrently because you cannot have two concurrent transactions on single connection.

The correct way is creating a new connection for each web service request. .NET by default uses connection pool so the performance impact is very small.

Comment: Does ADODB.Connection provide the connection pooling by default in C#.Net?

Comment: How do you create connection? Show some code in your question. Is it .NET connection or some interop?

Comment: Creating connection is like following

Comment: ADODB.Connection connection = new ADODB.Connection();And we are passing this connection to the C++ COM dll whcih would accept an IUnknown.And all the Db operationas are done uisng ADO Command and recordset object in C++.In this is there any way to incoperate the Connection pooling.